# Adding Tensorflow to my anaconda platform

Tags: tensorflow

I have been using anaconda environment. Now that I have installed tensorflow in my windows through the command prompt and following the necessary steps. I am not able to use tensorflow in anaconda platform. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please add what exactly have you tried and where things failed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a conda environment named tensorflow by invoking the following command:

   ```
   C:> conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
   ```
2. Activate the conda environment by issuing the following command:

   ```
   C:> activate tensorflow
   ```
3. Issue the appropriate command to install TensorFlow inside your conda environment. To install the CPU-only version of TensorFlow, enter the following command:

   ```
   (tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
   ```
4. To install the GPU version of TensorFlow, enter the following command (on a single line):

   ```
   (tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
   ```

You can read further by visiting [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)